# Enable source query syntax on TreelistEx control (not TreeList)

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm trying to make a custom field based on TreeListEx field, in reference to how a custom field was made using TreeList in this article:

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Custom%20TreeList%20that%20supports%20query.aspx

Basically I need to be able to enable query syntax in the source field. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: FYI, that article is for Sitecore 5.3. From your tags, I assume you're using v6?

Comment: yes, but it works for v6 as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - so, solved this one. ItemID is not available in the treelistex class as a property, but it is available as a value, and that value is in viewstate. So all you really need to do is expose the viewstate in an itemID property, and use it just like in the treelist control.

```
public string ItemID
        {
            get
            {
                return StringUtil.GetString(this.ViewState["ItemID"]);
            }
            set
            {
                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(value, "value");
                this.ViewState["ItemID"] = value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the [LuceneTreeListEx](http://trac.sitecore.net/LuceneTreeListExEditor) would save you any time in development. But to answer your question it should just be a case of creating a class that inherits from the TreeListEx control and overriding the Source property as in that example.

Essentially you are stripping the `query:` and passing it to the `database.SelectItems()` method.

You may want to look at the TreeListEx in reflector / DotPeek etc to see how its currently working.

Comment: yes, but unfortunately the source property needs the itemID to determine its context, which doesn't exist in treelistex, because the item doesn't actually execute until someones hits the 'edit' button